# What is the equivalent of the expression "you're putting me on the spot?"

Tags: phrase, idiom, expression

I'm looking for the German equivalent of the expression

> You're putting me on the spot.

Its meaning is something like being asked to do something, e.g. perform a song in the moment, impromptu, and/or without being given advance notice. It's usually accompanied with feelings of slight apprehension, nervousness, and perhaps embarrassment.

What is its German equivalent?

Comment: What did your dictionary search came up with? How do you use this expression/ what do you express when you use it?

Comment: When asking for a German equivalent of an idiom from another language, you should explain exactly what this idiom means - most users here are German natives and therefore probably not really familiar with the idiom in that other language.

Comment: It's like  being asked to do something, e.g. perform a song in the moment, impromptu, and/or without being given advance notice. It's usually accompanied with feelings of slight apprehension, nervousness, and perhaps embarrassment.

Comment: @LlamaWorm The most probably equivalent is "Du bringst mich auf den Punkt." Anyways your question is _off-topic_ here as currently written.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ How? This isn't a request for proofreading, spell checking, or the translation of an individual text.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖnot *auf den Spott*?

Comment: @sgf simply because the Q is putting us on the spot. I thought *Gewehr auf die Brust setzen*, which is maybe to harsh for what sounds like a hollywood spotlight set-up.

Answer (score 6):

"In Verlegenheit bringen" would be good.

"In eine unangenehme Lage bringen" would be somewhat synonymous. "Blamieren" would probably work, too, but that may be too strong. If someone intentionally puts someone else on the spot in order to get revenge or with intent to cause the other great discomfort, "jem. eins auswischen" would be ok, too.

Comment: Meines Erachtens ist das zu allgemein. Man kann auch durch ganz andere Dinge in Verlegenheit gebracht worden sein.

Comment: Das stimmt im Allgemeinen sicher, aber in diesem Kontext würde ich sagen, dass das eine passende Übersetzung ist.

Answer (score 6):

> Jemanden in Zugzwang bringen

*Zugzwang* means [compulsion to move](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zugzwang) and is used in games like chess, when it's a player's move but every move worsens their position.

However, it's not that strict colloquially. The German [wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zugzwang) says

> Umgangssprachlich bezeichnet der Ausdruck *Zugzwang* im Gegensatz dazu meist eine Situation, in der jemand zu einer bestimmten Handlung oder allgemein zu einer Reaktion auf eine Herausforderung gezwungen ist. Diese Handlung kann, muss aber nicht unbedingt nachteilige Folgen haben.

You "just" force someone to make a decision, it's not necessarily bad for them. This captures the meaning of "putting someone on the spot" better.

Your sentence would then translate to

> Du bringst mich in Zugzwang

Also possible is *jemanden unter Druck setzen* (put someone under pressure).

---

Aus dem [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/put-sb-on-the-spot)

> put *sb* on the spot
>
> If you put someone on the spot, you cause them embarrassment or difficulty by forcing them at that moment to answer a difficult question or make an important decision

Answer (score 4):

If someone is unprepared for a given task, she or he will probably reply:

> Da hast du mich auf dem falschen Fuß erwischt.

*Erwischen* literally means *to catch someone flat-footed*, and the *auf dem falschen Fuß* part is a reference to dancing. You flattened her or his foot.

Comment: _jemanden auf dem falschen Fuß erwischen_ is not a good translation of _to put someone on the spot_, because the English expression is referring to the person that puts you on the spot and is regardless of the feelings of the person that has to perform. Even if you are put on the spot, you can still master this. This is not possible if you are "auf dem falschen Fuß erwischt". I give -1 here.

Comment: +1. Doesn't always fit, but there's situations where it will, and I don't think there's one translation that always fits. By the way, I'd be very surprised if _auf dem falschen Fuß erwischen_ didn't come from fighting rather than dancing. (Where having your weight on the wrong foot will prevent you from parrying in time.) Do you have any references for the dancing context?

Comment: I was only told it was from dancing. But sword fight would be a better match, I think.

Comment: If the saying is old enough, *pod*, *pes* (see Indo European, Latin, Greek) might actually relate to *potis* and maybe even *spot* (in wordplay if norhing else*) +1

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, *to put someone on the spot* includes an element of forcing someone to make a decision (possibly causing the decider to "lose face", to choose between several undesirable options, or to spend some additional effort to decide faster than what would otherwise be the case) that could otherwise be given some more time (and be resolved more gracefully).

Idiomatically (and entirely figuratively), this is expressed in German by saying **die Pistole auf die Brust setzen**.

For example:

> With his surprising announcement, he's putting me on the spot.

becomes

> Mit seiner überraschenden Ankündigung setzt er mir die Pistole auf die Brust.

---

A difference between "jemanden in Zugzwang bringen", as suggested in other answers, is that "die Pistole auf die Brust setzen" happens actively and intentionally. "Jemanden in Zugzwang bringen" can also happen as an unintended side-effect, and may even go unnoticed by the one who causes the issue.

I'm not sure which one fits "to put someone on the spot" better in this respect.

Answer (score 0):

"**Jmd. in Zugzwang bringen**" finde ich gut, wobei für den Zugzwang aber gilt, dass dieser nicht immer mit öffentlicher Aufmerksamkeit verbunden sein muss. Ähnliches gilt für die Redewendung "**jmd. ins kalte Wasser werfen**", was gerne benutzt wird, wenn jmd. etwas bisher nur theoretisch gelernt hat, und es jetzt in die Praxis umsetzen soll.

Die Einschränkung mit der Öffentlichkeit gilt mehr noch für das "**die Pistole auf die Brust setzen**", welches eine Bedrohung ausdrückt, nicht notwendig eine rechtswidrige ("Wenn Sie jetzt nicht weiterfahren lasse ich Sie abschleppen!").

Der Spot erinnert auch an die dt. Floskel "jmd./etwas ins Rampenlicht stellen"; diese wird aber anders verwendet: Die öffentliche Aufmerksamkeit wird auf etwas gelenkt, aber ohne den Aspekt des Lampenfiebers mitschwingen zu lassen.

"**Du packst mich hier auf den Seziertisch**" wäre auch möglich, betont aber stark, dass das Publikum sehr kritisch hinschauen wird. Lampenfieber kann man aber auch bei einem wohlwollenden, wenig kritischen Publikum verspüren.

Comment: Woher stammt denn die Anforderung mit der öffentlichen Aufmerksamkeit?

Comment: Das Beispiel i.d. Frage habe ich so verstanden und ich dachte, der Spot käme vom Spotlight im Theater - liege ich da falsch?

Comment: Ins Kale Wasser werfen erfolgt in erster Linie ohne Aufforderung oder Ankündigung